# Extracting text from Bundestag proceedings as directed by XML files, and exporting to JSON

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, json, xml

I have a long script here that does the following for me: I have 9000 XML files, from which I parse information, and then in about 7000 TXT files find the information out, and in the end it all save as JSON. Well, aside from what he does, he does it very slowly.

Since I am very new to Python, I did not learn Python from books, but just try it out. The code here is normal fast up to 100 iterations, but from about 120 iterations it gets very slow.

What can I do against it? I've been looking for solutions like generators, Cprofile, Cython, pypy, and similar, but all too advanced for me. How can I optimize this code to make it run faster? `gc.collect()` did not help. I think it's more about the algorithm and the flow scheme, rather than what it does.

Sample Files: [Files](https://nofile.io/f/fo52WEC6mdy/files.zip)

cProfile Output: [cProfile Output](https://pastebin.com/RZUFYqpt)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import glob, os, re
import mpu.io


PATH_FINAL_XML = "/Users/x/PycharmProjects/BA/booking-system/final step/xml files"

PATH_FINAL_TXT = "/Users/x/PycharmProjects/BA/booking-system/final step/txt files"

os.chdir(PATH_FINAL_XML)

#path, dirs, files = os.walk(PATH).__next__()
#print("Files", len(files))

gesetzliste = list()

gesetzanzahlliste = list()

zeitliste = list()

br_list = ['Baden-Württemberg', "Bayern", "Berlin", "Bremen", "Hamburg",
            "Hamburg", "Mecklenburg-Vorpommern",
            "Nordrhein-Westfalen", "Niedersachsen", "Rheinland-Pfalz", "Saarland",
            "Sachsen", "Sachsen-Anhalt", "Schleswig-Holstein", "Thüringen", "Bundesregierung"]

MdB = "MdB"

pdf_xml_pattern = re.compile("(?<=\/)\d+(?=\.pdf)") # PDF Miner Pattern

split_pattern_president = r"\n+(?=(?:Präsident|Präsidentin|Vizepräsident|Vizepräsidentin)\s*(?:(?:Dr\.)*\s*[A-ZÖÜÄß]+[a-zöäüß]*\s*)*:)" # Präsident und Vizepräsident im BT

split_rest_pattern = r"\n+(?=(?:Dr\.)*\s*[A-ZÄÖÜ]*[a-züäö]*\s*[A-ZÄÖÜ]*[a-züäö]*\s*\([A-ZÜÄÖX\-,.\/\s]*\))" # alle außer, MdB, Minister, Gastredner etc.

zurufe_pattern = r"(\((?:(?!\bDokument\b|\bDrucksache\b|\bTagesordnung\b|\b(BÜNDNIS  90\/DIE  GRÜNEN)\b)[A-Za-z_äÄöÖüÜß\[\]\/,._–!?:;'\-—0-9]*\s){2,}[A-Za-z_äÄöÖüÜß;!.?\[\]\/,':-—–0-9]+[.,?!]*?\))" # um zurufe zu identifizieren


def two():

    for file in glob.glob("*.xml"): # xml path

        gesetz = dict()

        '''Childnode Lists'''

        schlagworterliste = list()

        sachgebietliste = list()

        drsliste = list()

        plenumliste = list()

        vorgangliste = list()

        speakeritems = list()

        mdb_splitterlist = list()

        mdb_not_splitterlist = list()

        splitterlist = list()

        '''Childnode Lists'''

        file_id = file.replace(".xml", "")
        print("Gesetzentwurf: ", file)

        tree = ET.parse(file)
        root = tree.getroot()

        for child in root:

            gesetz["File_ID"] = file_id

            if str(child.tag) == "SCHLAGWORT":
                schlagworterliste.append(child.text)
                gesetz[child.tag] = schlagworterliste

            elif str(child.tag) == "SACHGEBIET":
                sachgebietliste.append(child.text)
                gesetz[child.tag] = sachgebietliste

            elif str(child.tag) == "WICHTIGE_DRUCKSACHE":
                for child_wichtige_drucksache_herausgeber in child.findall("DRS_HERAUSGEBER"):
                    for child_wichtige_drucksache_nummer in child.findall("DRS_NUMMER"):
                        for child_wichtige_drucksache_typ in child.findall("DRS_TYP"):
                            drs = {child_wichtige_drucksache_herausgeber.tag:child_wichtige_drucksache_herausgeber.text,
                                   child_wichtige_drucksache_nummer.tag:child_wichtige_drucksache_nummer.text,
                                   child_wichtige_drucksache_typ.tag:child_wichtige_drucksache_typ.text}

                            drsliste.append(drs)
                            gesetz[child.tag] = drsliste

            elif str(child.tag) == "PLENUM":
                for child_plenum_klartext in child.findall("PLPR_KLARTEXT"):
                    for child_plenum_herausgeber in child.findall("PLPR_HERAUSGEBER"):
                        for child_plenum_nummer in child.findall("PLPR_NUMMER"):
                            for child_plenum_seiten in child.findall("PLPR_SEITEN"):
                                for child_plenum_link in child.findall("PLPR_LINK"):
                                    plenum = {child_plenum_klartext.tag:child_plenum_klartext.text,
                                              child_plenum_herausgeber.tag:child_plenum_herausgeber.text,
                                              child_plenum_nummer.tag:child_plenum_nummer.text,
                                              child_plenum_seiten.tag:child_plenum_seiten.text,
                                              child_plenum_link.tag:child_plenum_link.text}

                                    plenumliste.append(plenum)
                                    gesetz["PLPR"] = plenumliste


            else:
                gesetz[child.tag]  = child.text

            if "INITIATIVE" in gesetz.keys():
                if gesetz['INITIATIVE'] in br_list:
                    print("CONTINUE")
                    continue
            else:
                print("DEVAM")


            for child2 in child:
                for child_zuordnung in child2.findall("ZUORDNUNG"):
                    for child_urheber in child2.findall("URHEBER"):

                        if "Beratung" in child_urheber.text:
                            print("Beratung: ", child_urheber.text)

                            for child_fundstelle in child2.findall("FUNDSTELLE"):
                                vorgang = {child_zuordnung.tag:child_zuordnung.text,
                                           child_urheber.tag:child_urheber.text,
                                           child_fundstelle.tag:child_fundstelle.text}

                                for child_fundstelle_info in child2.findall("FUNDSTELLE_LINK"):
                                    get_xml = pdf_xml_pattern.findall(str(child_fundstelle_info.text))
                                    get_xml = "".join(get_xml)+".txt"

                                    for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(PATH_FINAL_TXT, '*.txt')): # txt path

                                        if get_xml in filename:
                                            with open(filename, "r") as txtfile:

                                                check_filename = filename[-9:-4] # for wp8 - wp12

                                                print("Sitzung:", check_filename+".txt")

                                                txt = txtfile.read()

                                                text = re.sub(r"^[\s\S]*?(?:eröffnet)", "", txt) 

                                                text = re.sub(r"((cid|\(cid):\d+\)|(Deutscher\s+Bundestag\s*\D*\s*\d*\W*\w*\s*\D*\s\d*\.\s*\w*\W*\w*\W*\w*\W*\w*\W*\d+\W*\w*\W*\d(\.\s+[A-Z_äÄöÖüÜß][A-Za-z_äÄöÖüÜß]*\s*\d*|\d+)))", " ", text)

                                                text = re.sub(r"(\(A\)|\(B\)|\(C\)|\(D\))", "", text)

                                                xml_page_pattern = r"(\d+[A-D])"

                                                page = re.findall(xml_page_pattern, child_fundstelle.text)

                                                page_begin = 0
                                                page_end = 0

                                                if len(page) < 2:
                                                    page_begin = int(page[0][:-1])-1; page_end = int(page[0][:-1])+1

                                                elif len(page) == 2:
                                                    page_begin = int(page[0][:-1])-1; page_end = int(page[1][:-1])+1


                                                get_pages_pattern = re.compile(r"(?<={})(.*)(?={})".format(page_begin, page_end), flags=re.DOTALL)

                                                text = get_pages_pattern.findall(text)

                                                text = "".join(text)


                                                for child_beschluss in child2.findall("BESCHLUSS"):
                                                   for beschluss_child in child_beschluss:
                                                       vorgang[beschluss_child.tag] = beschluss_child.text

                                                VORNAME = ""
                                                NACHNAME = ""
                                                FRAKTION = ""

                                                for child_speaker in child2.findall('PERSOENLICHER_URHEBER'):

                                                    speaker = {}

                                                    TITEL = ""
                                                    WAHLKREISZUSATZ = ""
                                                    FUNKTION = ""

                                                ############################################################################################################

                                                    for child in child_speaker:
                                                        speaker[child.tag] = child.text

                                                        if child.tag == "PERSON_TITEL":
                                                            TITEL = child.text

                                                        elif child.tag == "VORNAME":
                                                            VORNAME = child.text

                                                        elif child.tag == "NACHNAME":
                                                            NACHNAME = child.text

                                                        elif child.tag == "WAHLKREISZUSATZ":
                                                            WAHLKREISZUSATZ = child.text

                                                        elif child.tag == "FUNKTION":
                                                            FUNKTION = child.text

                                                        elif child.tag == "FRAKTION":
                                                            FRAKTION = child.text

                                                        else:
                                                            pass


                                                    ############################################################################################################


                                                    splitter_mdb = ""
                                                    splitter_only_name_mdb = ""

                                                    splitter_not_mdb = ""
                                                    splitter_only_name_not_mdb = ""

                                                    ############################################################################################################

                                                    if FRAKTION == "BÜNDNIS 90/DIE GRÜNEN": FRAKTION = "BÜNDNIS\s*90/DIE\s*GRÜNEN"

                                                    elif FRAKTION == "CDU/CSU": FRAKTION = "CDU\/CSU"

                                                    elif FRAKTION == "FDP": FRAKTION = "F\.D\.P\."

                                                    ############################################################################################################

                                                    if str(check_filename).startswith(("08", "09", "10", "11")): #WP

                                                        #print("here")
                                                        # only MdBs
                                                        if (not TITEL) and (not WAHLKREISZUSATZ) and (FUNKTION == MdB):
                                                            splitter_only_name_mdb = r"\n+(?=" + re.escape(NACHNAME) + "\s*\(" + "{}".format(FRAKTION) +"\))"

                                                        elif (TITEL) and (not WAHLKREISZUSATZ) and (FUNKTION == MdB):
                                                            splitter_only_name_mdb = r"\n+(?=" + re.escape(TITEL) + "\s*" + re.escape(NACHNAME) + "\s*\(" + "{}".format(FRAKTION) +"\))"

                                                        elif (WAHLKREISZUSATZ) and (not TITEL) and (FUNKTION == MdB):
                                                            splitter_only_name_mdb = r"\n+(?=" + re.escape(NACHNAME) + "\s*\(" + re.escape(WAHLKREISZUSATZ) + "\)\s*\(" + "{}".format(FRAKTION) +"\))"

                                                        elif (TITEL) and (WAHLKREISZUSATZ) and (FUNKTION == MdB):
                                                            splitter_only_name_mdb = r"\n+(?=" + re.escape(TITEL) + "\s*" + re.escape(NACHNAME) + "\s*\(" + re.escape(WAHLKREISZUSATZ) + "\)\s*\(" + "{}".format(FRAKTION) +"\))"

                                                        # only Minister etc.
                                                        elif (not FUNKTION == MdB) and (TITEL):
                                                            splitter_only_name_not_mdb = r"\n+(?=" + re.escape(NACHNAME) + "\s*\(" + "{}".format(FRAKTION) +"\))"

                                                        elif (not FUNKTION == MdB) and (not TITEL):
                                                            splitter_only_name_not_mdb = r"\n+(?=" + re.escape(TITEL) + "\s+" + re.escape(NACHNAME) + r",{0,1}\s*" + "{}".format(FUNKTION) + r"*\b(?:(?!\n\n)[^:])*:)"

                                                        elif (not FUNKTION == MdB) and (not TITEL):
                                                            splitter_only_name_not_mdb = splitter_not_mdb = r"\n+(?=" + re.escape(NACHNAME) + r",{0,1}\s*" + "{}".format(FUNKTION) + r"*\b(?:(?!\n\n)[^:])*:)"



                                                    else:
                                                        ############################################################################################################
                                                        ### Splitter Regex ###

                                                        # only MdBs
                                                        if (not TITEL) and (not WAHLKREISZUSATZ) and (FUNKTION == MdB):
                                                            splitter_mdb = r"\s+(?=" + re.escape(VORNAME) + "\s*" + re.escape(NACHNAME) + "\s*\(" + "{}".format(FRAKTION) +"\))"

                                                        elif (TITEL) and (not WAHLKREISZUSATZ) and (FUNKTION == MdB):
                                                            splitter_mdb = r"\s+(?=" + re.escape(TITEL) + "\s*"+ re.escape(VORNAME) + "\s*" + re.escape(NACHNAME) + "\s*\(" + "{}".format(FRAKTION) +"\))"

                                                        elif (WAHLKREISZUSATZ) and (not TITEL) and (FUNKTION == MdB):
                                                            splitter_mdb = r"\s+(?=" + re.escape(VORNAME) + "\s*" + re.escape(NACHNAME) + "\s*\(" + re.escape(WAHLKREISZUSATZ) + "\)\s*\(" + "{}".format(FRAKTION) +"\))"

                                                        elif (TITEL) and (WAHLKREISZUSATZ) and (FUNKTION == MdB):
                                                            splitter_mdb = r"\s+(?=" + re.escape(TITEL) + "\s*" + re.escape(VORNAME) + "\s*" + re.escape(NACHNAME) + "\s*\(" + re.escape(WAHLKREISZUSATZ) + "\)\s*\(" + "{}".format(FRAKTION) +"\))"

                                                        ############################################################################################################

                                                        # Minister etc. keine MdBs.
                                                        elif (not FUNKTION == MdB) and (TITEL):
                                                            splitter_not_mdb = r"\s+(?=" + re.escape(TITEL) + "\s+" + re.escape(VORNAME) + "\s+" + re.escape(NACHNAME) + r",{0,1}\s*" + "{}".format(FUNKTION) + r"*\b(?:(?!\n\n)[^:])*:)"

                                                        elif (not FUNKTION == MdB) and (not TITEL):
                                                            splitter_not_mdb = r"\s+(?=" + re.escape(VORNAME) + "\s+" + re.escape(NACHNAME) + r",{0,1}\s*" + "{}".format(FUNKTION) + r"*\b(?:(?!\n\n)[^:])*:)"

                                                        ### Splitter Regex Ende ###

                                                    ############################################################################################################

                                                    if FUNKTION == MdB:
                                                        mdb_splitterlist.append(splitter_mdb)
                                                        if str(check_filename).startswith(("08", "09", "10", "11")):
                                                            mdb_splitterlist.append(splitter_only_name_mdb)
                                                        else:
                                                            pass

                                                    elif FUNKTION != MdB:
                                                        mdb_not_splitterlist.append(splitter_not_mdb)
                                                        if str(check_filename).startswith(("08", "09", "10", "11")):
                                                            mdb_not_splitterlist.append(splitter_only_name_not_mdb)
                                                        else:
                                                            pass


                                                    ############################################################################################################
                                                    splitterlist = mdb_not_splitterlist + mdb_splitterlist


                                                    splitterlist.append(split_pattern_president)
                                                    splitterlist.append(split_rest_pattern)

                                                    str_list = list(filter(None, splitterlist))

                                                    splitted_text = []

                                                    try:

                                                        splitted_text = re.split(pattern='|'.join(str_list), string=text)

                                                        print("Split erfolgreich.")

                                                    except Exception as e:

                                                        print(e)

                                                        with open("logs-me.txt", "a") as logme:
                                                            logme.write(filename+" "+file_id+" "+file+"\n")

                                                        logme.close()

                                                        print("überspringe:", file_id)

                                                        continue


                                                    speeches = []

                                                    ############################################################################################################

                                                    for speechblock in splitted_text:

                                                        for speecher in splitterlist:

                                                            speecher = str(speecher[3:]).replace("=", ":") # regex

                                                            founded_speecher = re.findall(speecher, speechblock)

                                                            if (FUNKTION != MdB):
                                                                if (speaker['VORNAME'] in "".join(founded_speecher) and speaker['NACHNAME'] in "".join(founded_speecher)):

                                                                    speeches.append(speechblock)

                                                                    zurufe = re.findall(zurufe_pattern, speechblock, flags=re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)

                                                                    speech = {"TEXT":speeches, "ZURUFE":zurufe}

                                                                    speaker['INHALT'] = speech

                                                                    break #todo -> workaround

                                                            elif (FUNKTION == MdB):
                                                                if (speaker['VORNAME'] in "".join(founded_speecher) and speaker['NACHNAME'] in "".join(founded_speecher)
                                                                      or speaker['NACHNAME'] in "".join(founded_speecher) and speaker['FRAKTION'] in "".join(founded_speecher)):

                                                                    speeches.append(speechblock)

                                                                    zurufe = re.findall(zurufe_pattern, speechblock, flags=re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)

                                                                    speech = {"TEXT":speeches, "ZURUFE":zurufe}

                                                                    speaker['INHALT'] = speech

                                                                    break #todo -> workaround

                                                    speakeritems.append(speaker)

                                                    if "REDNER" in vorgang:
                                                        vorgang["REDNER"].append(speaker)
                                                    else:
                                                        vorgang["REDNER"] = [speaker]


                                    vorgangliste.append(vorgang)
                                    gesetz["VORGANG"] = vorgangliste

        if "INITIATIVE" in gesetz.keys():
            if gesetz['INITIATIVE'] in br_list:
                pass
            elif gesetz['INITIATIVE'] not in br_list:
                gesetzliste.append(gesetz)
            else:
                print("hier stimmt etwas nicht.")


        '''Write JSON FILE'''
        mpu.io.write("xssy33s.json", gesetzliste)

        print(len(gesetzliste))

two()
```

Comment: Can you add the output of the following command? `python -m cProfile -s tottime <filename>.py 100 1`

Comment: `cProfile` looks more complicated than it is. Read the manual and a couple of example uses, mess around a bit on smaller pieces of code and you'll figure it out in no-time at all.

Comment: @Mast I cannot run out the whole program, after 30 minutes its working verry slowly, so I cancel the execution. How long I should it run with your command? Thank you

Comment: If you can't run the whole program, how do you know it works correctly? Have you tried it using less files as input? That shouldn't matter much for profiling.

Comment: @Mast I mean, of course I did the whole code. Not only through all files. It works well with 10 files. But not with 1000. That's what I meant. After 100 files it gets noticeably slower that I track through the Command Line Outputs. So far I have not gotten all the files. And all files are the same size and same standards.

Comment: @Mast here is the output from your command. I test it with 1 XML File and the associated txt files. https://pastebin.com/3FFvaBHc

Comment: You should run the profiler with more than one file (but less than 1000). Obviously there is something which takes longer for each additional file (probably an `in` on some growing list or something like that), which is not visible when only running with one file.

Comment: understood. @Graipher I will try it now. Thank you for your help.

Comment: When you've profiled your code, please add the output to the question itself, not in the comments.

Comment: I have now a longer cprofile output about 6 hours. its seems to be the problem is on the re.split method. I have updated the post.

Answer (score 3):

## Runtime

This is the only obvious place I could find that looks like it might scale badly with an increasing number of files in the directory:

```
get_xml = pdf_xml_pattern.findall(
    str(child_fundstelle_info.text))
get_xml = "".join(get_xml) + ".txt"
# txt path
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(PATH_FINAL_TXT, '*.txt')):
    if get_xml in filename:
        with open(filename, "r") as txtfile:
            ...
```

This loops over all text files in the directory to find the ones that contains the correct name. Instead, filter as soon as possible:

```
get_xml = pdf_xml_pattern.findall(
    str(child_fundstelle_info.text))
# txt path
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(PATH_FINAL_TXT, "*{}*.txt".format("".join(get_xml)))):
    with open(filename, "r") as txtfile:
        ...
```

This assumes that there are multiple files that can fit. If there is only one, then it becomes even simpler:

```
get_xml = pdf_xml_pattern.findall(
    str(child_fundstelle_info.text))
# txt path
filename = os.path.join(PATH_FINAL_TXT, "".join(get_xml) + ".txt"):
with open(filename, "r") as txtfile:
    ...
```

---

## Style

Currently your code is one gigantic function. This makes it very hard to read (especially because the indentation level becomes very deep). Try to pull out single actions into their own functions, taking all relevant inputs as arguments and returning its results. This also allows you to give these functions names that make it more obvious what happens.

Code Review (and indeed the whole StackExchange network, except for some obvious exceptions, like Stack Overflow en español) is in English. This makes it a bit harder to get good reviews since your question contains a lot of German, since it is harder to read for most people.

However, what is actually worse is that you are not sticking to German names, either. You mix German variable names with English variable names (some of which contain grammatical errors, like `speecher_list`, which is probably supposed to be `speakers_list`). When programming I usually stick with English names, because it makes distributing your code easier and also it jars less that all the standard functions have English names.

Comment: I completely agree with all points in your post. I'll be more specific about your points in my future codes. I have just posted the cProfile output of about 6 hours. It looks like the problem lies with the re.split method, because the method gets more than 15 regexes with each iteration by the "|" .join.